# how to evaluate curve fitting in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab to analyse a couple of data, for I that I need  the curve fitting, I've wrote this code from the documentation :

```
% I is  14 points vector that change its value in a loop 

y =0:13;
[p,S] = polyfit(I,y,1);
[fx, delta] = polyval(p,I,S);
plot(y,I,'+',fx,I,'-');
```

here is what I get  : [image: plot]

my question is , how can evaluate this 'fitting', I mean how good it is  , and  how can I get the slope of this line?

**UPDATE**

after Rafaeli's answer , I  had some trouble understand the results, since `fx` is the fitting curve fitting for  `y` considering 'I' , meaning that I get for `fx':

```
-1.0454    3.0800   4.3897    6.5324   4.0947  3.8975   4.3476   9.0088  5.8307  6.7166 9.8243  11.4009  11.9223
```

instead the `I` values are :

```
 0.0021  0.0018   0.0017  0.0016  0.0018 0.0018 0.0017   0.0014  0.0016 0.0016  0.0014 0.0012 0.0012 0.0013
```

and the plot has exactly the  value of `I' :   [image]

so the result I hope to get  should be near to those values !  Itried to switch the

```
[p,S] = polyfit(y,I,1);
```

but is didn't the wasn't any better `fx= 0.0020`,so my question is how can I do that ?

**2nd UPDATE**
got it, here is the code :

y = 0:13 
p = polyfit(y,I,1)
fx = polyval(p,y);
plot(y,I,'+',y,fx,'o')

here is the result :

[image]

thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is defined by `y = ax + b`, where `a = p(1)` and `b = p(2)`, so the slope is `p(1)`.

A simple way to know how good is the fit is to take the root mean square of the error: `rms(fx - I)`. The lesser the value, better the fit.

Comment: just one question my data vector is I not y is it correct to use rms(fx-y)

Comment: You're right, my mistake! I'll edit the answer, thanks.